# How can I repaint circle, which is appended in the svg and dosn't show up?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, svg, backbone-views

I am trying to add g&circle tag in the svg tag.
I have to use Backbone View to do this. The Click event works well.
"However, the appended circle(SVG) tag doesn't show up on the browser, but the append does works one the html code."

Here is a html, below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="drawingdiv">
        <svg id="drawingSVG" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 95 50"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
<script data-main="main" src="libs/require-2.1.11.js"></script>
</html>
```

And I also have main.js of course.

```
require.config({
paths : {
    jquery : "libs/jquery-2.1.0",
    underscore : "libs/underscore-1.6.0",
    backbone : "libs/backbone-1.1.0",
    i18n : "libs/i18n",
    text : "libs/text"
}
});


require(["jquery", "shaperendererdrawingpanel"], function($, ShapeRendererDrawingPanel) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("doc-ready");
        var shapeRendererDrawingPanel = new ShapeRendererDrawingPanel();
    });
});
```

And I have shaperendererdrawingpanel.js.

```
define(["jquery", "backbone" ], function ($, Backbone) {

return Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#drawingdiv',
    events : {
        'mouseup #drawingSVG' :'mouseup'
    },
    mouseup : function(e) {
        alert(e.pageX + " " +e.pageY);
        //$('#drawingSVG').append('<g><circle cx="'+e.pageX+'" cy="'+e.pageY+'" r="'+10+'" fill="green"/></g>');
        $('#drawingSVG').append('<g><circle cx="11" cy="15" r="10" fill="green"/></g>');
        this.render();
    }
});
});
```

When I add new g & circle tag in the svg tag, the html code becomes like below after I click svg area. And It does work well, when I make another html file just using below code.

```
 <body>
    <div id="drawingdiv">
    <svg id="drawingSVG" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 95 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg>
       <g><circle cx="11" cy="15" r="10" fill="green"></circle></g>
    </svg>
    </div>
```

I think I have to repaint in the Backbone.View(shaperendererdrawingpanel).
How can I solove this problem.

Thank you very much, in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use jQuery to create SVG elements.  jQuery is intended for HTML only, and puts all created elements in the HTML namespace instead of the correct SVG namespace.

You need to either use one of the SVG JS libraries, or create the elements yourself using the DOM functions.  For example:

```
var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
mysvg.appendChild(g);
```